# Get html in ul outside li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code :

```html
<ul id="rubrique_1" class="questionZone ui-sortable">
Rubrique par défaut
<li id="question_1" class="questionStyle">(Q) Matrice case a coché</li></ul>
```

How can I get the HTML "Rubrique par défaut" without all the HTML of the li div with jQuery?
I don't want to put div for the text because I'm using sortable function on ul rubrique_1.

```js
$('#rubrique_1").text()
```

gives me all the HTML.

Comment: Your html is invalid, the [allowed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) for a `ul` is basically just `li` (and a couple of other edge cases) It can't contain text outside of an `li`. Also, your jQuery has two different types of quotation marks wrapping the selector, so it won't run.

Comment: If you can change the html move `Rubrique par défaut` in the <li> and wrap it with <span> with custom id. Then you can get it with $('#custom id").text()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

"give me all the html" -> `$("#rubrique_1").html()`

If you mean what I think you mean, you need:

```
$("#rubrique_1").contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }).text();
```

Hope this helps, but be sure to read DBS' comment

Answer (score -1):

Not direct but a little tricky solution. Pick the node with ID, With that selector, parse through all the child nodes inside that. Inside that list, check for nodes that are not `li` and have a valid text content (I have used trim function to check the content length).

```js
function decode () {
  let text = '';
  $('#rubrique_1')[0].childNodes.forEach(item => {
    text += item.tagName !=='LI' && item.data.trim().length > 0 ? item.data.trim(): '';
  }) ;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rubrique_1" class="questionZone ui-sortable">
  Rubrique par défaut
  <li id="question_1" class="questionStyle">(Q) Matrice case a coché</li>
  <li id="question_2" class="questionStyle">(Q) Matrice case a coché</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="decode()">Decode</button>
```

Comment: @BoudouftBilel if this is your requirement, please approve my answer. Happy to have an upvote :)